# How to convert existing java android into flutter (ERR in getLifecycle())

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I created an Android host application in the Android Studio 3.4.2 version and created a new project with type Empty Activity. After I successfully configure the Add-To-App in my host application, I plan to call the Flutter module in my host application, but I get an error when I want to call the Flutter screen in the getLifecycle() code. The error says Wrong 2nd argument type. Found "androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle", required "Lifecycle". How will I call the getLifecycle() function but not part of AndroidX?

The full source code is:

```
Button btnCall =  findViewById(R.id.btnFlutter);
        btnCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                View flutterView = Flutter.createView(MainActivity.this, getLifecycle(), "router1");
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(600, 800);
                layoutParams.leftMargin = 100;
                layoutParams.topMargin = 200;
                addContentView(flutterView, layoutParams);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but i got the solution:

Just go to new flutter module and from refractor option migrate it to Androidx